# Docker and OpenStack Benchmarking

Tags: ubuntu, docker, benchmarking, openstack

I'm doing a project for university with some friends and we wanted to compare Docker and OpenStack in terms of execution time for a simple script.
However, we're getting results that none of us can explain, so I'm hoping someone can explain whether we did things wrong or if we just lack of knowledge to understand what happened.

Here is the simple 'prime.sh' script

```
   num=14293;
    i=2
    while [ $i -lt $num ]; do
        if [ `expr $num % $i` -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "Divisible by $i"
            exit
        fi
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
    echo "$num is a prime number "
```

What we did was to execute it with the Unix time command (like `time ./prime.sh`) on a Ubuntu Server 14.04 instance in OpenStack, on an Ubuntu Server 14.04 in Docker and on the Host OS (also Ubuntu Server 14.04) itself. On each system we executed the script 10 times.

Our results were:

```
OpenStack     16,48 Sec
Docker:       25,77 Sec
HostOS:       30,45 Sec
```

Can someone please help trying to explain?
We don't get, why the script needs almost twice as long to execute on the Host OS as it does on open stack, and also, why openstack is 8secs faster than docker.

PS.
On Unix, 'time' outputs real, user, and sys time, while docker and the HostOS were pretty short in sys and user time (around 3 and 1secs, both) OpenStack needed almost 16secs in sys time. I don't know if that changes anything as the real time should be the important one, but maybe it helps to understand?

EDIT: 1

For execution we ssh'ed into the OpenStack Ubuntu Instance, touched the script there and then executed it from command line.
The same happened for Docker, here we used `docker exec -it ourubuntu bash` to get the container and there created and executed the script.

The command to execute the scripts always was
`time ./prime.sh`
In fact we used a simple for loop
`for i in`seq 1 10`; do time ./prime.sh; done`
to get a number of results.

EDIT: 2
With a new Script using $(( .. )) instead of `expr ..` the execution times are a lot more understandable.
Now, the Host OS executes the code the fastest, second comes docker, OpenStack needs a bit longer then the others

Comment: You appear to be missing a semicolon after the 'do'. Is that just a copypaste typo? (I edited it in, but asking to be sure.)

Comment: I'm a little skeptical that your code is actually running exactly what you wrote in the question. (For one thing, there was the question of the syntax error.) Are your tests actually returning the same _value_ on each system?

Comment: Yes, the code is running as expected, on all systems it returns that 14293 is a prime number, I don't think that there lays the problem. As all systems are based on Ubuntu 14.04, I will rerun the tests with the semicolon

Comment: OK, please also add to the question a description of exactly how you are invoking the tests. The more precisely, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would point out is that this code is spending a huge amount of time doing things like subshell expansions of `expr`, which seems to be beside the point. If you use bash, you can get a much faster result for small primes (without changing the algorithm):

```
prime1() { 
  local -i num="$1"
  local -i i=1 
  while (( i++ < num )); do
    (( num % i )) && continue
    printf '%d is divisible by %d\n' "$num" "$i"
    return
  done
  printf '%d is a prime number\n' "$num"
}
```

(If you're targetting /bin/sh or dash, you would need to write it in a more POSIXLY_STRICT manner, like this:

```
prime2() {
  local num="$1"
  local i=2
  local cur
  while [ $i -lt $num ]; do
    cur=$(( $num % $i ))
    if [ $cur -eq 0 ]; then
      printf '%d is divisible by %d\n' "$num" "$i"
      return
    fi
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
  done
  printf '%d is a prime number\n' "$num"
}
```

My tests yield these results on El Capitan using bash:

```
$ ./prime 
Running prime1
14293 is a prime number

real    0m0.168s
user    0m0.160s
sys 0m0.006s
Running prime2
14293 is a prime number

real    0m0.323s
user    0m0.303s
sys 0m0.019s
Running prime_orig
14293 is a prime number 

real    0m46.016s
user    0m19.682s
sys 0m25.132s
```

So just for comparison, you're losing over 46 seconds on calls that have nothing to do with the prime comparison. That makes me suspect that there's something funky with the method of your invocation itself. For example, you could be passing the script to the vm in such a way that makes the host responsible for expanding the `expr` subshells, it could save the vms a lot of processing time.

It's all conjecture now, but provide more info in the question and I'll flesh it out.

Comment: I will try the tests without the `expr` clause.
However, I can't quite understand how this clause should make the host use twice as much time as the vm.

It is not about the algorithm, I know that this one is really not optimized, we just needed something that needs a couple of seconds to  execute, that's why we used this standard prime calculation

Comment: @Nymokrit have you ruled out that one of the systems is just much busier?

Comment: We tried to do so. 
All the tests happened on the same laptop, 8GB of RAM, Intel i5 Processor, Ubuntu Server 14.04 as Host. ------ Before invoking the tests for docker and the host-only we stopped all running processes from open stack and rebooted the computer

Comment: @Nymokrit let me know how it goes with the tests that don't have subprocesses, please. (It's not the `expr` that's the problem _per se_, but the fact that you are asking the shell to fork/exec for a subprocess that makes those calls extremely expensive to make in a loop.)

Comment: I'm working on running the updated script on open stack, that will take a while but for now I can tell you that with the prime number 500009 the docker container needed around 6 seconds, the host itself needed about 8 seconds

Comment: Okay, I was able to test it now, removing the `expr` statement fixed the results. With slight changes in the script now running the code on the host OS needs around 4.9 to 5.2secs, Docker also 5 - 5.2 and the Instance, running on OpenStack uses 5.2 - 5.5 secs

Comment: @Nymokrit ok, that's progress, but you don't have a root cause yet. Hypotheses: fork/exec on the host is more expensive than on the vm/container due to kernel configuration.

Comment: Jep, I tried to find out more about that but couldn't find anything helpful online, yet. I'll do a bit more research tomorrow on that topic